# Is there any reason why both WebElements and locators shouldn't be used in one Selenium test project

Tags: java, selenium, automated-tests

In my Selenium tests, I sometimes need to use locators (eg. driver.findElement(locator)) and sometimes I need to use webElements (eg. List). I wonder if there is any reason, that using these to in one project is not correct and I should stick to one type and declare only locators or only webElements in every pageObject.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If I am correctly understanding what you are asking, I've found that while it is generally possible and most convenient to declare all or most of what you need for testing as webElements on a pageObject, it is sometimes necessary to dynamically use locators directly in the tests to identify certain elements.  I'm guessing that's what you've run in to when you say you "sometimes need to use locators".

In general, I'd say it is generally easier to read something like

```
myCheckBox.click();
```

rather than

```
driver.findElement(possiblyCrypticLocator);
```

and obviously it would be convenient to define webElements whenever you need to reuse them.

However I don't see an inherent reason to avoid "mixing" locators and webElements if you need to use the locators dynamically.  Others might disagree.

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood you Question properly, your Question is regarding the `Locators` and `finding element(s)`

### Locators :

Locators are used to search for elements in the **`Current Browsing Context`**. As per the current **`W3C WebDriver Specs`** the following table of location strategies lists the keywords and states defined for this attribute:

[image]

### Locator Examples:

We are free to use any of the following locators to find/search/identify element(s):

- **`CSS`**

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("my_cssSelector"));
  ```
- **`Link Text`**

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.linkText("my_linkText"));
  ```
- **`Partial Link Text`**

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("my_partialLinkText"));
  ```
- **`Tag Name`**

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.tagName("My_iframe"));
  ```
- **`Xpath`**

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("my_xpath"));
  ```

### Finding WebElement(s):

**`WebElement`** is an interface which represents an **`HTML element`**. Generally, all the user operations to interact with a page will be performed through this interface. **`findElement()`** and **`findElements()`** are two among the several implemented methods. These methods call will do a check to ensure that the element reference is still valid as per the current state of the **`DOM Tree`**. This essentially determines whether the intended element is still attached to the `HTML DOM` or not.

- **`findElement()`**

  ```
  findElement(By by) //Find the first WebElement using the given method.
  ```
- **`findElements()`**

  ```
  findElements(By by) //Find all elements within the current context using the given mechanism.
  ```

The major difference between the two is, **`findElement()`** returns the **`WebElement`** where as **`findElements()`** returns a **`List<WebElement>`**. But we can use any of the above two methods anywhere in our Project as per necessity and requirement.